# CSS Alignment of a link next to an image

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/Fn4vP/4/).

The link "follow us" is next to the twitter icon. What I want is for the link to be vertically centered on the image using `css` without inline styles if possible.

I've tried adding a class directly to the `<a>` tag and then adjusting the margin. That did not work.

I tried adding a class directly to the `img` tag and then adjusting the margin. That did not work.

I tried doing both of these things again adjusting the padding instead of the margin.

Is this even possible the way I have it set up or am I going to have to change the `html`..or both?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Here is an article in case IE give you some trouble
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would `float` the image to the left, then change the `line-height` of the `a` tag to be equivalent to the height of the image (in this case, 19px). To target the line height only to the anchor surrounding "Follow Us," just add a class to the anchor like `.follow`.

**HTML**

```
<img src="imageURL.png" width="24px" height="19px">
<a href="#" class="follow"> Follow Us</a>
```

**CSS**

```
img { float: left; }
.follow { line-height: 19px; }
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn4vP/17/)

Comment: Well vertical-align:middle is neater and simpler, why not use it?

Comment: I find that the `vertical-align` property can very for some browsers, especially for IE.

Comment: @JSW189 : where did you "find" that? it works very well if used in the right situations, which here is the case (inline elements like img, a, etc. to align vertically).

Comment: @darma I have "found" that through my own experience with the property. But I may be wrong. Feel free to prove me wrong by showing a browser compatibility chart.

Comment: Also, why was my answer downvoted? I don't think it is an "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: @JSW189 : The problem with vertical-align is that it is too often misinterpreted and used in situations where it is bound to fail, which leads to disapointment in those cases and to false believings. Nevertheless it is a good tool to have, and it is supported by all major browsers as stated here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15276/discussion-between-jsw189-and-darma)

Answer (score 5):

You can set `vertical-align:middle` both on the `<a>` and `<img>` you wish to align.

**Edit :** see http://jsfiddle.net/Fn4vP/16/

Comment: I thought vertical-align was a deprecated element.

Comment: "align" as an attribute is deprecated yes, but not at all the CSS property !

Answer (score 0):

I would use `line-height`, Basically, float your image left, float the link left and then clear the floats on the next `<h3>` tag.
Change this part to the following:

```
<!-- Dont forget to close your image tag.  -->
<img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2ly6hc4.png" width="24px" height="19px"/>
<a href="#" class="flw-link"> Follow Us</a>
<!-- Added class .flw-link to Follow us link -->
```

Now in your CSS:

```
/* Float the image and link to the left */
.twitter-feed img{float: left;}
/* Set the line-height of the text to center vertically to the image */
.twitter-feed .flw-link{float: left; line-height: 21px;}
/* Finally, clear your floats on the next tweet header */
.twitter-feed h3{clear: both;}
```

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fn4vP/25/

I would do it like this and float both elements, because I have to option to change the line-height to `0` which will position the text right at the top. You can then use the line-height to have pixel control over exactly where the text is positioned vertically.