# Align image and list on same line in html

Tags: html, css

Currently I am trying to create a header section in HTML, which contains a logo image and a list which is being used as a navigation menu.
The problem which I am facing right now is that, when I am giving a certain height to the list(equivalent to image height) the height of the list is going downwards against the image, and I want to be on the same line and text of the list in the middle. The following is the code snippet of my page.

```css
.header-section>img
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.navigation,.navigation ul
{
    list-style:none;
}
.navigation
{
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navigation>li
{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}

.navigation ul
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!--Header section-->
<div class="header-section">
 <img src="images/logo/logo.png" alt="logo" width="90px" height="30px">
 <!--Navigation section-->
 <ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">About &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Founders</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Mission</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Products  &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Panels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Lamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Heaters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Cookers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Services &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Equipment Repair</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Support &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Contact &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Email Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <!--Social Icons-->
 <img src="images/icons/twitter.png">
 <img src="images/icons/facebook.png">
 <img src="images/icons/google-plus.png">
</div>
<!--Header section closed-->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Alignment of a link next to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935565/css-alignment-of-a-link-next-to-an-image)

Comment: put your logo menu's etc in table -> td tag

Comment: your question not clear to me, but i think you need to add a `margin: 0;` for `.navigation`

Comment: *"equivalent to image height"* There is no any height given to image.

Comment: logo height is defined 30px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a vertical-align attribute to your images

```
.header-section > img
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Update :** Float version
Add a "float left" attribute to your images and .navigation and set an image "height + padding" equal to the line-height of your list.

```css
.header-section
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-section > img
{
    float: left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.navigation
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
.navigation
{
    background-color:red;
}
.navigation > li
{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
.navigation ul
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!--Header section-->
<div class="header-section">
 <img src="images/logo/logo.png">
 <!--Navigation section-->
 <ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">About &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Founders</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Mission</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Products  &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Panels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Lamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Heaters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Cookers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Services &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Solar Equipment Repair</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Installation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maintenance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Support &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
   <a href="#">Contact &#x25BC;</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Email Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Form</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <!--Social Icons-->
 <img src="images/icons/twitter.png">
 <img src="images/icons/facebook.png">
 <img src="images/icons/google-plus.png">
</div>
<!--Header section closed-->
```

Comment: Vertical alignment worked. I applied it to the image tag and list tag. Now both of them are on equal lines. But is there any other way? like without the usage of vertical align, can I align the list and the image equally on the same line?